# Api google adwords - client_secret for oAuth2.0

Tags: google-oauth

I have a problem with api adwords. I don't have client_secret from code.google.com/apis/console. 
I created project and I add API Access for my application but i don't see client_secret in box Service account.

I have Client ID, Email address, Public key fingerprints, private key, and client_secret.json. In api adwords for php is config file auth.ini:

```
[OAUTH2]

; If you do not have a client ID or secret, please create one of type
; "installed application" in the Google API console:
; https://code.google.com/apis/console#access
client_id = "INSERT_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID_HERE"
client_secret = "INSERT_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
...
```

But I don't have client_secret.
What i did wrong? or could give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP application you are trying to use probably does not work with service accounts.

In order to get a client secret you have to create a client id of type "Web application".